# Directive scope unreachable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to "share" a scope between two directives as follow:

```
toolbarActions.directive('toolbarActions', function (toolbar) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.toolbarActions = toolbar.getActions();
        },
        template: "<div class='centered-div-container'>" +
                         "<toolbar-action ng-repeat='toolbarAction in toolbarActions' icon-source='{{toolbarAction.icon}}'></toolbar-action>>"+
                   "</div>",
    };
});
```

The inner directive looks like this:

```
toolbarActions.directive('toolbarAction', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
           iconSource: '&'
        },
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.imageUrl = attrs.iconSource;
        },
        template: "<div class='centered-div-content header-control' ng-click='actionFunction()'>" +
                         "<img ng-src='{{imageUrl}}' /> "+
                   "</div>",
    };
});
```

In the following simple HTML:

```
<div class="header-content">
   <toolbar-actions></toolbar-actions>
</div>
```

However, no matter what I do, I can't make the icon-source retrieve the correct value (toolbarAction.icon), but rather an exception is thrown:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'toolbarAction.icon' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 3 of the expression [{{toolbarAction.icon}}] starting at [toolbarAction.icon}}]. http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/$parse/syntax?p0=toolbarAction.icon&p1=is%20unexpected%2C%20expecting%20%5B%3A%5D&p2=3&p3=%7B%7BtoolbarAction.icon%7D%7D&p4=toolbarAction.icon%7D%7D minErr/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78
```

I've tried many versions of replacing the scope definition on the toolbarAction directive (such as:)

```
scope:true
    or
scope:false
```

And tried many transculsion combinations as well.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I think the best solution in your case is to use the $parse service, remove the scope of your toolbarAction directive and watch for any modification of the parsed attribute.

In toolbarActions directive replace {{toolbarAction.icon}} by toolbarAction.icon only :

```
template: "<div class='centered-div-container'>" +
            "<toolbar-action ng-repeat='toolbarAction in toolbarActions' icon-source='toolbarAction.icon'></toolbar-action>"+
          "</div>"
```

And your toolbarAction directive becomes something like :

```
.directive('toolbarAction', function ($parse, toolbar) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var getImgURL = $parse(attrs.iconSource); //get the raw json path and create a function out of it
      //Get notified when the value is reversed
      scope.$watch(getImgURL, function(value) {
        //Finally store the real value to be used in your directive template
        scope.imageUrl = value;
      });
    },
    template: "<div class='centered-div-content header-control' ng-click='actionFunction()'>" +
                 "<img ng-src='{{imageUrl}}' /> "+
               "</div>",
  };
});
```

I have assembled a working plunker accessible [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/s6YVinmSyiW2TSYRwnx1?p=preview) with this you should be all set :)

Comment: This is a nice fix, thanks, but I could also simple ask the scope and get the same results by replacing the first line on the link function with:
scope.imgUrl = scope.toolbarAction.icon;
which will also work.. But I still don't get why putting {{toolbarAction.icon}} in an attribute of mine doesn't work, while inside a tag, such as <span>{{toolbarAction.icon}}</span> (in the toolbarAction template) it works perfectly.